# How right align bootstrap form button?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Please tell me how right align this form "Log in" button using bootstrap. I tired to use pull-right class. But after resizing my button is not in the correct position.

```
<div role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control"/>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
        </label>
    </div>

    <button class="btn-info btn">Log in</button>                            
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried the class `pull-right`?

Comment: yeah, but after done it, button goes down

Comment: I don't see any problem while resizing the Browser. check here. http://jsbin.com/cajogozetewi/1

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use `text-right` first you have to wrap it in a `div` like this:

```
<div class="text-right">
     <button class="btn-info btn">Log in</button>
</div>
```

## [LIVE-DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8x4fmcq9/)

Here is the full code

```
<div role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control"/>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"/> Remember Me
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="text-right"> <!--You can add col-lg-12 if you want -->
        <button class="btn-info btn">Log in</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I second this. Using `pull-right` to float an element can very often lead to undesirable layout problems.

Comment: text-right worked for bootstrap form, whereas pull-right would put the buttons outside form, so if form has a bkg, buttons would be outside that bkg

Answer (score 13):

`pull-right` is working fine

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/orw1akwn/3/)

```
<button class="btn-info btn pull-right">Log in</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside a container with rows and columns in Bootstrap4, all the floats don't work properly.

Instead you have to add a spacer column to get things to align.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<p>Float right demo inside a container-fluid, Bootstrap 4</p>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col bg-warning"></div><!-- This is the filler column -->
    <div class="col-auto bg-success">.col-auto (Like a Float Right)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.